# Lock / Unlock mac osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

I am searching for support for lock / unlocking the screen in Yosemite. 
There are some apps like fingerKey , MacID , Tether which does the same.
Is there any support from Apple frameworks for the same. 
My App is needs to lock the device after a certain duration and after 5 minutes need to unlock itself.

Comment: Did you finally found a code for this? Lock is easy, I am interested in unlock part.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Authorization Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html).